# Airflow read the trigger dag dag_run.conf content

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to Airflow.I would like read the Trigger DAG configuration passed by user and store as a variable which can be passed as job argument to the actual code.
Would like to access all the parameters passed while triggering the DAG.

```
def get_execution_date(**kwargs):
    if ({{kwargs["dag_run"].conf["execution_date"]}}) is not None:
        execution_date = kwargs["dag_run"].conf["execution_date"]
        print(f" execution date given by user{execution_date}")
    else:
        execution_date = str(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    return execution_date
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Jinja templating as you did.

The `{{kwargs["dag_run"].conf["execution_date"]}}` will not be rendered.

You can access DAG information via:

```
dag_run = kwargs.get('dag_run')
task_instance = kwargs.get('task_instance')
execution_date = kwargs.get('execution_date')
```

Comment: What is `context`? I mean, how do you get `context`? Is it from dag? or from some package?

Comment: @JaybePark It is typically passed to the function as a kwarg list of arguments. Such as def _execute(**context):

Answer (score 0):

Passing variable in Trigger Operator (airflow v2.1.2)

```
    trigger_dependent_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="trigger_dependent_dag",
        trigger_dag_id="dependent-dag",
        conf={"test_run_id": "rx100"},
        wait_for_completion=False
    )
```

Reading it in dependent dag via `context['dag_run'].conf['{variable_key}']`

```
def dependent_fuction(**context):
    print("run_id=" + context['dag_run'].conf['test_run_id'])
    print('Dependent DAG has completed.')
    time.sleep(180)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).