# Airflow: Jinja template not being rendered in subdag pythonOperator

Tags: airflow

I am passing a set parameters in SubDagOperator function which then calls PythonOprerator but the Jinja Template or macros are not getting rendered

```py
  file_check = SubDagOperator(
    task_id=SUBDAG_TASK_ID,
    subdag=load_sub_dag(
        dag_id='%s.%s' % (DAG_ID, SUBDAG_TASK_ID),
        params={
            'countries': ["SG"],
            'date': '{{ execution_date.strftime("%Y%m%d") }}',
            'poke_interval': 60,
            'timeout': 60 * 5
        },
        start_date=default_args['start_date'],
        email=default_args['email'],
        schedule_interval=None,
    ),
    dag=dag
)
```

now in the load dag operator call an pythonOperaor as

```py
def load_sub_dag(dag_id, start_date, email, params, schedule_interval):
    dag = DAG(
        dag_id=dag_id,
        schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
        start_date=start_date
    )

   start = PythonOperator(
        task_id="start",
        python_callable=get_start_time,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )

   
   file_paths = source_detail['path'].replace('$date', params['date'])
   file_paths = [file_paths.replace("$cc", country) for country in params['countries']]
        for file_path in file_paths:
            i += 1
            check_files = PythonOperator(
                task_id="success_file_check_{}_{}".format(source, i),
                python_callable=check_success_file,
                op_kwargs={"file_path": file_path, "params": params,
                           "success_file_name": success_file_name,
                           "hourly": hourly},
                provide_context=True,
                retries=0,
                dag=dag
            )

            start >> check_files
    return dag
```

Now, as far as I know, the jinja template should get rendered in the op_kawrgs section of check_file pythonoperator but it is not happening rather I am getting the same string in final file name

Also when I see task details I see file name as u'/something/dt={{ execution_date.strftime("%Y%m%d") }}'

Airflow ver - 1.10.2 &
celeryexecutor

Comment: You can't use Jinja in params . I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/65302348/14624409 should solve your issue

Comment: Also what is source_detail ?

Comment: @Elad source_detail is just a global dict containing path templates with $date and other params which are replaced according to needs

Comment: but source_detail also has params['date'] ? I just don't fully understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Elad the source details contains path template and params is another dict which is an arg in load_sub_dag and params['date'] returns the date in string format and source_details['path'] returns a path as "/somethin/otherthing/dt=$date" and $date date is replaced with params['date'] which a date string or the jinja template which should convert to date later on

Comment: @Elad checked out your answer you tagged , but I don't think it will work in this case as I don't have context variable or Kwargs in the place where I am actually using the date and also I want the date to be custom ,i.e date can be as '20210526' or execution_date

Comment: Where is the code where you actually use the date? I think the issue is that you need to access it in the check_success_file callable (just like I showed in the answer) and your attempts to handle it before cause you the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232925/discussion-between-reyahamed-and-elad).